# a porblem with plot(), learning from "Data analysis and R programming Laurent Gatto 2017-11-10"

Tags: r, plot

I'm super new in R. This is my `str`:

```
'data.frame': 34786 obs. of 13 variables:
 $ record_id      : int 1 72 224 266 349 363 435 506 588 661 ...
 $ month          : int 7 8 9 10 11 11 12 1 2 3 ...
 $ day            : int 16 19 13 16 12 12 10 8 18 11 ...
 $ year           : int 1977 1977 1977 1977 1977 1977 1977 1978 1978 1978 ...
 $ plot_id        : int 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ species_id     : chr "NL" "NL" "NL" "NL" ...
 $ sex            : chr "M" "M" "" "" ...
 $ hindfoot_length: int 32 31 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ weight         : int NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 218 NA ...
 $ genus          : chr "Neotoma" "Neotoma" "Neotoma" "Neotoma" ...
 $ species        : chr "albigula" "albigula" "albigula" "albigula" ...
 $ taxa           : chr "Rodent" "Rodent" "Rodent" "Rodent" ...
 $ plot_type      : chr "Control" "Control" "Control" "Control" ...
```

When I try to run `plot(surveys$sex)`, the following error appears: "Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values". In addition, I receive the following warning messages:

1. "NAs introduced by coercion"
2. "No non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf"
3. "No non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `plot(factor(surveys$sex))`. The guide you are following is probably out of date. In older versions of R character values were coerced to factors automatically when you imported data. This is no longer the default.

Comment: `sex` is a character variable, `plot` needs numeric variables. Maybe `barplot(table(sex))` is what you want?

Comment: thanks! plot(factor(surveys$sex)) worked. sorry, not sure how to comment directly to your comment @MrFlick